# Invocation of init method failed: com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPChannelProperties.getConnectRetriesPerHost()

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jmx, solace-mq

So I have this bean file which is being called in a java file. For the love of god I cannot figure out why I have this error.

I tried doing my research on the internet or read about JCSMPChannelProperties (which I didn't find).

Tried changing the order of beans (which should not matter).

Probably has an easy fix. But I cannot figure it out!!!

```
    Error creating bean with name 'broadCastService' defined in URL [file:/C:/EclipseWorkspace/NewWorkspace/ss_cache/bin/cacheQueryServiceContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cacheQueryService' while setting bean property 'genericQueryService'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cacheQueryService' defined in class path resource [muniOfferingQueryServiceContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'muni.JmsTemplate' while setting bean property 'jmsTopicTemplate'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'muni.JmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [muniOfferingQueryServiceContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'muni.SolaceCachedConnectionFactory' while setting bean property 'connectionFactory'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'muni.SolaceCachedConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [muniOfferingQueryServiceContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'muni.SolaceConnectionFactory' while setting bean property 'targetConnectionFactory'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'muni.SolaceConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [muniOfferingQueryServiceContext.xml]: 


    Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPChannelProperties.getConnectRetriesPerHost()I
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to copy/paste one of the answers I got from a question I asked last week.

*A NoSuchMethodError is almost always due to conflicting library versions. In this case I'm guessing there are multiple versions of joda libraries in the two projects.*

Similarly, you probably have multiple versions of the same library. You can check where resources are getting loaded from by using the following code (also copy/pasted from my answer).

```
Class cls = your.clazz.Here.class; 
ProtectionDomain pDomain = cls.getProtectionDomain();
CodeSource cSource = pDomain.getCodeSource();
URL loc = cSource.getLocation();
System.out.println(loc);
```

Question for Reference: [NoSuchMethodError - Calling Class/Method from Class in Same Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624124/nosuchmethoderror-calling-class-method-from-class-in-same-package)